# How can I save a list of QObjects into a file?

Tags: pyqt4

I would like to save a list of QObjects into a file and read it again in the easiest way possible. Can I use QDataStream for this (writeListVariant, readListVariant)? How can I do this?

Comment: 1) Are they purely QObjects, or are they instances of subclasses?  2) what aspect of the objects are you hoping will be recorded? Dynamic properties? Signal/slot connections?

Comment: In particular I am looking to save session information from qtwebkit.